# Applications named with special characters not showing up in the Dash

Tags: unity-dash, special-characters

I recently downloaded and installed LÖVE (note the special character).  If I type L in the dash, it is nowhere to be found.  EVEN if I just launched LÖVE from the launcher, it does not show up in the "recent apps" section of the dash.

Is there an issue with apps with special character/the dash??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dash will search through your .desktop files and use the name provided and comments so that you don't have to enter "Firefox", for instance. Entering "web" will do just as fine, since "web" is part of the description of Firefox.

In the case of LÖVE, the application developer has specifically asked that the application should not show up in menus by specifying NoDisplay=True in the desktop file. I don't know exactly why they've done this, but it might be because it requires a filename input in order to do anything useful.

If you think this should be different, you can file a bug with the LÖVE developers by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `ubuntu-bug love`.

Comment: thanks so much, that explains it!  If I make the .desktop file read/write, can I change this w/o causing other issues?

Comment: Yes. You might have to log out and back in for it to become effective though, since I'm guessing they're read at login. I don't know this. But it's just a text file so you can edit as you please.